# Unix command to create directory and go into it

Tags: shell, unix, command

Generally, I've to hit two commands:

```
$ mkdir dir_name
$ cd dir_name
```

to create directory and go to it.

Is there single command by using which we can achieve above?

Comment: You could make a shell script that takes a name parameter and then does the two actions you specify with that variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine them both into a single command:

```
$ mkdir dir_name && cd dir_name
```

Note that the second half will run only if the first half succeeds. That is, if your directory already exists, it will *not* change directories.

If you want to change directory regardless, use a semicolon instead:

```
$ mkdir dir_name; cd dir_name
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add a function in your `.bash_profile`:

```
function mkdircd () { mkdir -p "$@" && eval cd "\"\$$#\""; }
```

And use it like:

```
mkdircd test_folder
```

Comment: way too complex, but good to know :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:-

```
$ mkdir dir_name && cd dir_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it like this

```
$ mkdir dir_name && cd dir_name
```

The shell will interpret `&&` as a logical `AND`. When using `&&` the second command is executed only if the first one succeeds (returns a zero exit status).

Answer (score 2):

Still two commands, but if you just want to avoid typing the directory name twice you can do this:

```
$ mkdir name
$ cd !$
```